# Posting data when my caled class has a constructor does not work

Tags: c#, angularjs, post

In C# I have the following code:

```
public class MeasurementListController : BaseController
{
    readonly MeasurementListService _mlS;
    public MeasurementListController(MeasurementListService mlS)
    {
        _mlS = mlS;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WidgetGridGetList()
    {
        return JsonData(_mlS.GetMeasurementDataGridList());
    }
}
```

when I call a function WidgetGridGetList in angular it gets ignored

```
$http.post("MeasurementList/WidgetGridGetList");
```

but when I remove a constructor it work. Why is that?

Comment: You need to provide another Parameterless constructor. `public MeasurementListController {  }` that sets a default value for `_mlS`

Comment: what does the constructor with parameter do ?

Comment: it initialize class for Services

Comment: * it initialize class for Services* using what value ? You don't create a controller yourself, it is automatically created and needs a constructor with no parameters (or some automatic dependency injection mechanism).

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to read this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

Think about it. This is a class, each request needs to create an instance of the controller and then calls the needed method (action).

When you remove your custom constructor, C# automatically creates a hidden default public constructor.

```
public MeasurementListController() : base()
{

}
```

However, when you declare a custom constructor, then there is no default Parameter-less constructor. At this point, how can a controller be created per request ? And What is the value for `_mlS` ? This is where the problem lies.

In the working case, the request can easily create through reflection an instance of the controller using `new MeasurementListController()`. But when you introduce your new constructor, then it needs to pass an argument of type `MeasurementListService` which is impossible in that case because it doesn't have it [ `new MeasurementListController(???)` ].

To solve this, you need to introduce a default constructor:

```
readonly MeasurementListService _mlS;

public MeasurementListController()
{
     _mlS = /* some default value */;
}

public MeasurementListController(MeasurementListService mlS)
{
   _mlS = mlS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not my code. I am just trying to fix some stuff.

The whole cycle looks like that:

**Controller:**

```
public class MeasurementListController : BaseController
{
    readonly MeasurementListService _mlS;
    public MeasurementListController(MeasurementListService mlS)
    {
        _mlS = mlS;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WidgetGridGetList()
    {
        return JsonData(_mlS.GetMeasurementDataGridList());        
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class MeasurementListService
{
    readonly MeasurementListRepository _mlR;

    public MeasurementListService(MeasurementListRepository mlR)
    {
        _mlR = mlR;
    }

    public virtual IList<Location> GetMeasurementDataGridList()
    {
        return _mlR.GetLocations();
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public class MeasurementListRepository
{
    readonly IDbConnection _db;

    public MeasurementListRepository(IDbConnection db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IList<Location> GetLocations()
    {
        return _db.Query<Location>(@"select * from Location").ToList();
    }
}
```

and a call from js:

```
$http.post("MeasurementList/WidgetGridGetList");
```

That is the whole cycle.